# How can I draw a point with Canvas in Tkinter?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I want to draw a point in Tkinter,Now I'm using `Canvas` to make it,but I didn't find such method to draw a point in `Canvas` class.`Canvas` provides a method called `crete_line(x1,y1,x2,y2)`,so i tried to set `x1=x2,y1=y2` to draw a point, but it doesn't work.

So anyone can tell me how to make it,it will be better if use `Canvas` can make it,other solution will be also accepted.Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method to directly put a point on `Canvas`. The method below shows points using `create_oval` method.

Try this:

```
from Tkinter import *

canvas_width = 500
canvas_height = 150


def paint(event):
    python_green = "#476042"
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
    w.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=python_green)



master = Tk()
master.title("Points")
w = Canvas(master,
           width=canvas_width,
           height=canvas_height)
w.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
w.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)

message = Label(master, text="Press and Drag the mouse to draw")
message.pack(side=BOTTOM)

mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks!It works well,although not directly as I thought,and I'm wondering why `create_line` can't and `create_oval` can.

Comment: create_line can do this but you have to give the line some dimensions. If x1 == x2 and y1 == y2 then you have a zero pixel line. So set x2 = x1+1 and y2 = y1+1 and get a single point.

Comment: Sorry, but this is an awful drawing, even for an example, besides being almost out of topic. The questionner asked how to daw **a point**. All you had to indicate was just `canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+1, y+1, fill={color})`.

Comment: @Apostolos Indeed, offtopic answer. One could also do it by self.canvas.create_line(x,y,x,y,width=5, fill='red', capstyle=ROUND, smooth=TRUE, splinesteps=1)

Answer (score 5):

The provided above solution doesn't seem to work for me when I'm trying to put a sequence of a few pixels in a row.

I've found another solution -- reducing the border width of the oval to 0:

```
canvas.create_oval(x, y, x, y, width = 0, fill = 'white')
```

Answer (score 5):

With create_line you have other possible workaround solution:

```
canvas.create_line(x, y, x+1, y, fill="#ff0000")
```

It overwrites only a single pixel (x,y to red)

Answer (score 2):

Since an update of the Tk lib (somewhere between Tk 8.6.0 and 8.6.9) the behavior of create_line had changed.
To create a one pixel dot at (x, y) in 8.6.0 you add to write

```
canvas.create_line(x, y, x+1, y, fill=color)
```

Now on 8.6.9 you have to use:

```
canvas.create_line(x, y, x, y, fill=color)
```

Note that Debian 9 use 8.6.0 and Archlinux (in early 2019) use 8.6.9 so portability is compromised for a few years.