# How reference back a paint event on Python Canvas using Tkinter?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I know this is probably the simplest question ever. However, I'm getting started on learning Tkinter and I don't know how to reference back the event for when a mouse click takes place on the GUI.

I want to draw some points when I click on the canvas. I cannot reference back the canvas variable in the paint function.

This piece of code is based on the question here in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888580/how-can-i-draw-a-point-with-canvas-in-tkinter)

Whenever I attempt the example I get an error in the paint function that says

> NameError: name 'canvas' is not defined;

```
def main():
    master = Tk()
    # Right side of the screen / img holder
    right_frame = Frame(master, width=500, height=500, cursor="dot")
    right_frame.pack(side=LEFT)

    # Retrieve image
    image = Image.open("./image/demo.JPG")
    image = image.resize((800, 700), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    # Create canvas
    canvas = Canvas(right_frame, width=800, height=700)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor="nw")
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)
    message = Label(right_frame, text="Press the mouse to draw")
    message.pack(side=BOTTOM)


    mainloop()


def paint(event):
    python_green = "#476042"
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
    canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=python_green)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can't see a use for the pandas tag, so replaced it with more relevant ones.

Comment: Ups thanks, I didn't see it was selected when I submitted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple mistake with python's scoping rules. Variables that you create in a function are not available to use outside of that function.

```
>>> def func():
...   a = 42
... 
>>> func()
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

You have to pass the canvas to the paint function. To do this via `bind` we need to make a "closure", which we can do with the `functools.partial` function.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

def main():
    master = Tk()
    # Right side of the screen / img holder
    right_frame = Frame(master, width=500, height=500, cursor="dot")
    right_frame.pack(side=LEFT)

    # Create canvas
    canvas = Canvas(right_frame, width=800, height=700)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor="nw")
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", partial(paint, canvas))
    message = Label(right_frame, text="Press the mouse to draw")
    message.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    mainloop()

def paint(canvas, event):
    python_green = "#476042"
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
    canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=python_green)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You really should think about a class structure for these kinds of programs, so that you can make variables available to other methods.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have now created a class structure.